# Crystal Reports 2013 Passing multiple values parameter as one comma delimited string to subreport

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, subreport

A strange error comes from passing multiple string parameters from a main report to a subreport

1.The Main Report contains a multiple value parameter called {?CPT Codes}.

2.Formula field `@DisplayCPTCodes` concatenates these values together with a comma delimiter into a single string using this formula: `"'"&Join({?CPT Codes},"','")&"'"` producing a string like

> 'J2405', 'J1100'

3.A subreport is passed `@DisplayCPTCodes` into it's own {?CPT Codes} parameter
[image: Subreport is linked to Main Report with Formula Field concatenating multiple string values into one string]

4. I get a strange error when I try to use {?CPT Codes} in the SubReport Command. Even something as simple as `SELECT {?CPT Codes}` in the SubReport Command produces the following error message
   [image: TSQL Error using linked parameter in subreport command]

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you run `Select '{?CPT Codes}'` - Is there ever a trailing comma (like, an extra comma at the end of the string)?

Comment: I don't think you can use `SELECT {?CPT Codes}` as {?CPT Codes} is not a database field... what is the requirment are you writing any command in sub report

Comment: Yes, you can include parameters and variable as part of the select statement. `select '{?test}' as test`

Answer (score 0):

Error 102 is Incorrect syntax near ')'
When you are creating the command double click on parameter to insert it, do not type it